I have an issue where a script made for creating a virtual player works but also doesn't work
I'm having trouble with a Java program that attempts to connect to a Minecraft server and send a chat message. The script encounters errors when the server is not running, but it works without issues when my LAN server is active. However, there is no confirmation from the Minecraft server that any actions have occurred.
Here's my program:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

    public class VirtualPlayer {
        private Socket socket;
        private DataInputStream in;
        private DataOutputStream out;
    
        public VirtualPlayer(String address, int port) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + address + " on port " + port);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    
            // Send handshake packet
            sendHandshake(address, port);
    
            // Send login packet
            sendLogin();
    
            // Wait for login response before sending chat message
            waitForLogin();
    
            // Send chat message
            sendChatMessage("Hello from VirtualPlayer!");
    
            // Log connection status
            System.out.println("Connected successfully!");
        }
    
        private void sendHandshake(String host, int port) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Sending handshake...");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream packet = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            writeVarInt(packet, 0x00); // Packet ID for Handshake
            writeVarInt(packet, 340); // Protocol version for Minecraft 1.12.2
            packet.writeUTF(host); // Server address
            packet.writeShort(port); // Server port
            packet.writeByte(1); // Next state: login
            sendPacket(baos.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Handshake sent.");
        }
    
        private void sendLogin() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Sending login...");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream packet = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            packet.writeByte(0x00); // Login Start packet ID
            packet.writeUTF("VirtualPlayer"); // Username
            sendPacket(baos.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Login packet sent.");
        }
    
        private void waitForLogin() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Waiting for login response...");
    
        while (true) {
            if (in.available() > 0) {
                int packetId = in.readByte(); // Read the packet ID
                System.out.println("Received packet ID: " + packetId);
    
                switch (packetId) {
                    case 0x02: // Replace with actual login success packet ID
                        System.out.println("Login successful.");
                        return; // Exit loop on successful login
                    case 0x01: // Replace with actual login failure packet ID
                        System.out.println("Login failed.");
                        return; // Exit loop on failed login
                    default:
                        readPacket();
                        System.out.println("Received unexpected packet ID: " + packetId);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100); // Avoid busy-waiting
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void sendChatMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sending chat message...");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream packet = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        writeVarInt(packet, 0x01); // Packet ID for Chat Message
        packet.writeUTF(message); // Chat message content
        sendPacket(baos.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("Chat message sent.");
    }
    
    private void sendPacket(byte[] packet) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sending packet: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(packet));
        out.write(packet);
        out.flush();
    }
    
    private void readPacket() throws IOException {
        if (in.available() > 0) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
            in.readFully(buffer);
            baos.write(buffer);
            System.out.println("Received packet: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray()));
        }
    }
    
    private void writeVarInt(DataOutputStream out, int value) throws IOException {
        while ((value & 0x80) != 0) {
            out.writeByte((value & 0x7F) | 0x80);
            value >>>= 7;
        }
        out.writeByte(value);
    }
    
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Closing connection...");
        socket.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            VirtualPlayer player = new VirtualPlayer("127.0.0.1", 53861);
            // Wait to observe behavior
            Thread.sleep(5000); // Wait for 5 seconds
            player.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

The script works only when the LAN server is running. When the server is off, it throws errors which are expected if the server is down. When connected to the LAN server, there is no feedback from the Minecraft server indicating that the handshake, login, or chat messages were processed correctly.
What I need help with:

Understanding why there is no confirmation from the Minecraft server regarding the handshake, login, or chat messages.
= Verifying whether the program correctly handles packets and interactions with the server.
Guidance on how to troubleshoot networking issues and validate that the client is functioning as intended.

I have researched YouTube videos and documentation, but found them either too advanced or not detailed enough for my current level of understanding. Any advice on how to fix these issues or resources to guide me through this process would be greatly appreciated.
